# Spring SAML: Multiple ACS URLs?

Tags: spring, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I'm trying to configure Spring SAML to work with multiple ACS URLs. I'd like the ACS URL to be determined based on some input the user provides, and it will select one of two ACS urls.

For example:

- The user passes in a value `A` in the request, the ACS URL will be `http://server1.com/saml/response`.
- The user passes in a value `B` in the request, the ACS URL will be `http://server2.com/saml/response` in the SAML Response

Any ideas or pointers in the right direction would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what version of Spring Security SAML you're using. This is an example based on `1.0.10.RELEASE` and is available [here](https://github.com/apereo/saml2-sample-java-webapp/).

This is one way to do it:

```java
public class ConfigurableWebSsoProfile extends WebSSOProfileImpl {

    @Override
    protected AuthnRequest getAuthnRequest(final SAMLMessageContext context,
                                           final WebSSOProfileOptions options,
                                           final AssertionConsumerService acs,
                                           final SingleSignOnService bindingService)
        throws SAMLException, MetadataProviderException {

      
        AuthnRequest request = super.getAuthnRequest(context, options, 
                                 acs, bindingService);
        if (something == true) {
           request.setAssertionConsumerServiceURL(...);
        } else {
           request.setAssertionConsumerServiceURL(...);
        }
        return request;
    }


}
```